# Camera auto focus not working on Galaxy S4

Tags: android, android-camera

I use this snippet to make camera focus on document:

```
// set focus mode is auto
List<String> supportModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
// find appreciate focus mode. In this case, the focus mode is 'auto' 
camParameters.setFocusMode(focusmode);

camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

@Override
public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
    // do something after focusing  
}
});
```

I put the `autoFocus` method in a timer, it 's called with 5 seconds interval. My code worked fine on many devices (Galaxy ace, note 3, S3...) except Galaxy S4. From debug, I can see `onAutoFocus` callback get called, but there is nothing happened with camera and surface view. Camera doesn't focus on anything. The image on surface view is very blur. Does anyone know this bug?

Comment: Try replacing your line with this one: `parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);`

Comment: @gilonm actually, I tried all focus modes but still not work.

Comment: Are you by any chance manually setting the preview size?

Comment: Yes. I setup preview size with ratio aspect as Zxing app. And I reference this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17157549/719212 but not work too.

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM?

Comment: No, official Rom, android 4.3

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas :-(

Answer (score 0):

Don't you forget the

```
mCamera.setParameters(camParameters);
```

after

```
 camParameters.setFocusMode(focusmode);
```

?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13821501)

Comment: If this line is missing it doesn't work. That may be an answer to the problem!